# Python scripting in linux

Tags: python, django, linux, fabric

We have around 250 identical linux server which runs a business critical web application for a bank. Basically we do a lot of scripting work but now i want to centralize that only in one location. That means run on one server and and deploy it in many. I know you guys must be thinking that this is an easy task and can be done with a shell script. But again we need to create many different different scripts to do our work

I know python has a big library and this can be possible but i dont know how. To cut in short i need all scripts in one file and based on the argument it will execute it according.

For example in a python program we have a function where we can mix them to perform different result.

So you please let me know how to go about it

Comment: "please let me know how to go about it".  um..  You'd write Python code to do it.  It's not clear what you're asking.  Do you want us to write the scripts for you?  Your idea is good.  What do you need that you haven't already figured out?

Comment: let me make it clear for you. i did mention that i dont want a mess of scripts.i come from a web application developer background.the setup what we have right now is we are using differnt scripts to complete our task.since i am a fan of python i thought that there might be an easy way.

Comment: @fear_matrix: There is an easy way.  Python with scripts and arguments.  You've already explained (in the question). It's a good solution.  What more do you need to know?

Comment: @S.Lott anyways i have just checked out fabric and this is exactly what i need.........

Comment: @fear_matrix: Which of your requirements in the question is satisfied by `fabric`?  Can you explain how it's possible from the given information to conclude that `fabric` is relevant?

Comment: @S.Lott well i can install Fabric on a server, and then i can push the  deployments by running remote commands via ssh on a set of servers and this is exactly what i needed

Comment: @fear_matrix: "can push the deployments by running remote commands via ssh on a set of servers"?  Is that what the question is about?  Perhaps you could revise it to clarify it so that others can learn from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very general question, so I'll respond with two different frameworks that are made using Python to facilitate bulk system administration tasks.

1. [func](https://fedorahosted.org/func/) - Func is part of the
   Fedora project and so is specialized
   to their architecture. If your hosts
   are all RedHat/CentOS based, this is
   the solution for you.
2. [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html) - Fabric is more generic
   but does generally the same thing at
   a high level.  If your environment
   is heterogenous (full of different
   types of systems/distributions),
   this is probably what you want.

Comment: +1 for Fabric - although I wonder if something like Puppet or Chef is really what the OP needs, even though they're written in Ruby.

Comment: thanks a jathanism. Fabric is exactly what i require. Just one question is it stable enough ??

Comment: Stable enough to rely on?  It works very well for me!  Give it a try and you'll have to decide for yourself. I hope it does, because I love fabric.

Comment: Upvoting this answer because you've made a decent stab at an almost impossible question.

Comment: HAHA, I saw "250 identical linux servers", "scripting", "centralized", and "python". Working in security, I've become very good at figuring out requirements based on... feelings.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try any of the distributed computing packages.  Pyro is one of them that might interest you.